# How to convert keras float predictions to int?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting the error

> File "/anaconda/envs/tf3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 830, in compile
>       sample_weight, mask)
>     File "/anaconda/envs/tf3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 445, in weighted
>       score_array *= weights
>     File "/anaconda/envs/tf3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 898, in binary_op_wrapper
>       y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
>     File "/anaconda/envs/tf3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 932, in convert_to_tensor
>       as_ref=False)
>     File "/anaconda/envs/tf3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1022, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>     File "/anaconda/envs/tf3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 866, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
>       (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
>   ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("global_average_pooling2d_1_sample_weights:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)'

during the training phase.

Running the latest `Keras (2.1.3)` and `TensorFlow (1.5)` through `Conda`.

Here is a minimum code that reproduces the error:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model

import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

def test_loss(y_input, x_input):

    x1 = K.cast(x_input, dtype='int32')
    y1 = K.cast(y_input, dtype='int32')

    loss = K.square(x1 - y1)


    reduced_loss = K.cumsum(loss)

    return reduced_loss

train_data = 10*np.random.rand(1600, 18,18,512)
validation_data = 10*np.random.rand(200, 18,18,512)

Y_train = np.random.rand(1600, 803)
Y_test = np.random.rand(200, 803)

#model
inputs = Input(shape=train_data.shape[1:])
x = Conv2D(803, (1,1), activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
predictions = GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:])(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=test_loss,  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_data, Y_train,
              epochs=200,
              batch_size=1,
              validation_data=(validation_data, Y_test))
```

Comment: why you are casting to int32 ??  
If you replace with 
    `x1 = K.cast(x_input, dtype='float32')
    y1 = K.cast(y_input, dtype='float32')` 
The error will disappear

Comment: I need to cast to int to get quantized values.  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You use np.argmax